# using jax lax scan with inputs that don't change across iterations within scan but are different each time scan is called

Tags: jit, jax

Jax lax scan operates on a function that takes two arguments, a carry and a sequence of inputs. I am wondering how scan should be called if some inputs don't change across iterations of the scan. Naively, I could create a sequence of identical inputs, but this seems wasteful/redundant and more importantly, this isn't always possible, as scan can only scan over arrays. For example, one of the inputs I want to pass to my function is a train state (e.g. from flax.training import train_state) that contains my model and its parameters, which cannot be put into array. As I say in the title, these inputs may also change each time I call scan (e.g. the model parameters will change).

Any ideas on how best to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have three possible approaches for this:

1. Convert the single value into a sequence of identical inputs to scan over
2. Put the single value in the `carry` to carry it along to each step of the scan
3. Close over the single value

Here are three examples of a computation using these strategies:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

a = jnp.arange(5)
b = 2
```

```py
# Strategy 1: duplicate b across sequence
def f(carry, xs):
  a, b = xs
  result = a * b
  return carry + result, result

b_seq = jnp.full_like(a, b)

total, cumulative = jax.lax.scan(f, 0, (a, b_seq))
print(total) # 20
print(cumulative) # [0 2 4 6 8]
```

```py
# Strategy 2: put b in the carry
def f(carry, xs):
  carry, b = carry
  a = xs
  result = a * b
  return (carry + result, b), result

(total, _), cumulative = jax.lax.scan(f, (0, b), a)
print(total) # 20
print(cumulative) # [0 2 4 6 8]
```

```py
# Strategy 3: close over b
from functools import partial

def f(carry, xs, b):
  a = xs
  result = a * b
  return carry + result, result

total, cumulative = jax.lax.scan(partial(f, b=b), 0, a)
print(total) # 20
print(cumulative) # [0 2 4 6 8]
```

Which you use probably depends on the context of where you are using it, but I personally think closure (option 3) is probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Are these strategies all equally efficient. In particular, I'm wondering if partial is similar to static_argnums with jit, in which the code has to be recompiled every time the variable (b in your example) changes its value, which I understand will make things very slow. For me, this variable will be changing constantly during model training (as it contains model parameters).

Comment: Closure is not the same as declaring static arguments; for example it is possible to close over traced values. Regarding re-compiles, it depends where you put the `jit`. If your `scan` operation is within a `jit`-compiled function, then the `partial` solution won't lead to re-compiles. If your `scan` is not within an outer `jit`, then it will lead to a re-compile each time you change the `b` value.